# user unable to log in with passport Js on ios

Tags: ios, node.js, passport.js

I have a nodejs/express app that runs passport js with local strategy for auth.

Everything works well so far, but i have one user who is unable to log in from his iphone 6s . it doesn't matter which browser (safari,chrome etc) he use. we tried allowing cookies, deleting history and changing different setting on his device but nothing helps.

he has no problem logging in using different devices or his desktop computer.

this is my set up for passport auth :

```
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false,  { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false,  { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.post('/home',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: 'main',
                                   failureRedirect: '/',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

I get this flash message when he tries to log in : ["Incorrect username..Incorrect username"]

any ideas how to debug or solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried other ios devices?

Comment: @JoshuaSkrzypek yes, it works fine on other devices